# GridView buttons not working correctly

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I have a GridView and am using a BaseAdapter to populate the values for each grid item. I am programmatically adding the buttons in each grid item using this adapter. The problem is, I have a total of SEVEN buttons. After each button click, the button is disabled so can only be clicked once.

So when the second button is clicked, the 7th button stops working. And if the 7th button is clicked, the first button stops working. The buttons are working fine and function properly apart from this.

**EDIT:** It seems like scrolling through the gridview (since the elements inside the gridview are large is causing the problem.)

Here is the relevant code.

**MyAdapter.java**

```
        import static com.example.tuss.mafia.R.layout.layout_grid_item;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Players> playerList;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Players> playerList){
    this.context = context;
    this.playerList = playerList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return playerList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout_grid_item, null);

    final Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRoleReveal);
    TextView idTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_id);
    TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_name);
    final TextView roleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_player_role);

    Players p;
    p = playerList.get(position);
    idTextView.setText("ID: " + String.valueOf(p.getId()));
    nameTextView.setText(String.valueOf(p.getName()));
    roleTextView.setText("Your Role Is: " + String.valueOf(p.getRole())+ ", you won't be able to view this again.");

    final String role = roleTextView.getText().toString();

    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("Remember your role and keep it a secret!")
                    .setMessage(role)
                    .create()
                    .show();
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                    button.setText("Role has been viewed");
            return true;
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

The XML for the gridview, **fragment_viewroles.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tuss.mafia.GameActivity" >



<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gv_players"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:gravity="center">
</GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**layout_grid_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/customborder"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_player_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="ID" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_player_name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:text=""
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_player_role"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="role"
    android:visibility="invisible">
</TextView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hold to reveal your role"
    android:id="@+id/btnRoleReveal"
    />
```

**RolesFragment.java**

```
public RolesFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_viewroles, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gv_players);
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    playersList = new ArrayList<Players>();

    playersList = databaseHelper.getPlayers();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), playersList);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing .create() for your alert dialog.

Comment: .show() and .create() are the same?

Comment: Actually .show() shows the dialog whereas .create() creates the dialog. when you call .show() it actually calls .create() also..And another thing while using fragment in onCreateView method you should only call findviewbyid method.Other things  you have to do in onActivityCreated().

Comment: can you please post your full adapter code?

Answer (score 0):

replace  button.setEnabled(false); with  ((Button)v).setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your button event. 
Just Initialize button event once

```
if (convertView == null){
    convertView = inflater.inflate(layout_grid_item, null);
    Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRoleReveal);
    button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Button btn = (Button)v;
        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Remember your role and keep it a secret!")
                .setMessage(role)
                .create()
                .show();
                btn.setEnabled(false);
                btn.setText("Role has been viewed");
        return true;
     }
    });
}
```

[Check this KodeCenter example](http://kodecenter.com/article?id=b0c6ea94-23d9-4810-abeb-1f4870e5318b)